# a:before pseudo element not clickable in IE 8/9/10

Tags: css, internet-explorer, pseudo-element

I'm trying to update the ui of an existing program, using only CSS. Where possible, I'm trying to use CSS elements in place of background images.

I'm using a :before pseudo element to add an arrow for a drop-down menu. This works great in FF, Chrome, and IE 11+. However, in IE 8/9/10, the pseudo element is not clickable (just shows a text cursor). The pseudo element is being placed on an anchor element.

Below is the simplified code. You can see this in a fiddle:  https://jsfiddle.net/ejw6gxpb/

HTML:

```
<a href="#">select</a>
```

CSS:

```
a {
    text-indent:9999px;
    font-size:0px;
    width:16px;
    height:16px;
    overflow:hidden;
    position:relative;
}

a:before {
    content:"\25bc";
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    right:0;
    font-size:12px;    
}
```

So far, I've tried changing the z-index, giving the a and a:before elements an opacity of 0, and playing with the sizing, background colors, and positioning. Nothing seems to make a difference. Any ideas?

Comment: have you tried removing the `text-indent` property?  actually i think it is clickable - try using `cursor: pointer;` to see the cursor change

Comment: Removing the `text-indent` (or making it 0) doesn't seem to make a difference. Changing the `cursor` at the element or pseudo-element level also does not make a difference. For some reason, I'm having trouble with the fiddle today - the pseudo element seems to be working correctly in IE 9 and 10, and the fiddle is not displaying at all in IE 8. I'll update if I get a better fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

In working with my fiddle, I realized that in my example above I said the `:before` was applied to the `a` element, when in reality I had actually applied the `:before` to the container element.

I think the `:before` content was sitting on top of the `a` element, in essence covering it up. Once I realized that, I was able to correct the situation to that it now works nicely across browsers.

Thank you!